# How can I handle WinRT IInputStream in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-runtime

I like to read the battery status of connected bluetooth headsets. Using a script I want to be able to print it on my Win10 desktop with something like [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/).

I'm using WinRT namespaces to successfully find and connect to my Bluetooth headsets, but to open a stream and read the contents (e.g. battery status) I have to deal with an Interface.

What I got working so far:

```
#Add Type WinRT so that we can make use of Universal Windows Platform (UWP)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime

#To deal with asynchronous functions/actions in WinRT we can use the following functions: Await and AwaitAction
#With thanks to Ben N. on https://superuser.com/questions/1341997/using-a-uwp-api-namespace-in-powershell
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
Function AwaitAction($WinRtAction) {
    $asTask = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and !$_.IsGenericMethod })[0]
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtAction))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
}

#Get the relevant DeviceId from $btDeviceAll(not shown here for brevity)
$SonyWH1000XM3id = 'Bluetooth#Bluetoothac:##:##:##:##:##-##:##:##:##:##:##'

#Get relevant btDevice by referencing the DeviceId.
$btDeviceClass = [Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,Windows.Devices.Bluetooth,ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
$btDevice = Await ($btDeviceClass::FromIdAsync($SonyWH1000XM3id)) ([Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice])

#Choose the relevant $btRfcommServices.services[] from $btRfcommServices(not shown here for brevity, my sony headset has HFP handsfree policy available)
$btHFPServiceUUID = '0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'
$btHFPConnectionHostName = '##:##:##:##:##:##'
$btHFPConnectionServiceName = 'Bluetooth#Bluetoothac:##:##:##:##:##-##:##:##:##:##:###RFCOMM:00000000:{00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}'

#Connect to the device with a StreamSocket
[Windows.Networking.HostName,Windows.Networking,ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
[Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket,Windows.Networking.Sockets,ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
$btHostName = [Windows.Networking.HostName]($btHFPConnectionHostName)
$btSocket = New-Object Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket
AwaitAction ($btSocket.ConnectAsync($btHostName,$btHFPConnectionServiceName))
```

Now, to get actual data I need to use the `$btSocket.InputStream` [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream?view=winrt-22000) via:

1. the method: `IInputStream.ReadAsync(IBuffer, UInt32, InputStreamOptions)`; or
2. the class `DataReader(IInputStream)`.

Unfortunately, .InputStream is an interface IInputStream but Powershell sees an System.__ComObject and I have no idea how to tell Powershell what it is. Therefore, the second method with DataReader(IInputStream) produces an error. The first method, by Invoking ReadAsync gives me `Object of type 'System.__ComObject' cannot be converted to type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction'` when:

```
$InputStreamOptionPartial = [Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions]::Partial
$btByte = New-Object Byte[] 1024
$btIBuffer = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions]::AsBuffer($btByte)
$bfSize = [UInt32]"1024"
$btReadAsync = [Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream].GetMethod('ReadAsync',[type[]]@('Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer','UInt32','Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions'))
AwaitAction ($btReadAsync.Invoke($btSocket.InputStream,@($btIBuffer,$bfSize,$InputStreamOptionPartial)))
```

BTW: I've also tried performing it al in C# script in Powershell, but I can't even get C# script to use WinRT namespaces, only `using system.io` etc.

Can someone explain to me (or type out) how to get DataReader() to accept the StreamSocket.IInputStream or get a working Buffer from ReadAsync?? Alternative scripting solutions are also welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream.readasync?view=winrt-22000#windows-storage-streams-iinputstream-readasync(windows-storage-streams-ibuffer-system-uint32-windows-storage-streams-inputstreamoptions)), `IInputStream.ReadAsync()` returns `IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer,uint>` and you are trying to use `AsTask(IAsyncAction)`.

Here is an example of using `AsTask(IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer,uint>)`:

https://gist.github.com/lselden/ab2e04fbac785e0644c4b562bf5e35cd

```powershell
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? {
    $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and 
    $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and 
    $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress`2' })[0];

Function AwaitWithProgress($WinRtTask, $ResultType1, $ResultType2) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType1, $ResultType2)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
}
```

Then you could run your invoke method like this:

```powershell
AwaitWithProgress ($btReadAsync.Invoke($btSocket.InputStream,@($btIBuffer,$bfSize,$InputStreamOptionPartial))) ([Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer]) ([UInt32])
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was looking in that direction, but couldn't get it to work. I've changed it a little bit, more in line with the link you supplied (i.e. added `MakeGenericMethod($ResultType1, $ResultType2)` and `$netTask.Result` to get some minimal input from my Jabra headset.
My Sony WH1000XM3 however gives me DeniedBySystem on the relevant RFcomm service so I have some work to do yet. Thanks for getting me this part of the puzzle!

Comment: @Mr.Scooter You are right. I left out important stuff. Corrected and made it a little more readable. I am guessing that your Sony headset service is probably connected to something and that is why it won't let you connect.

Comment: Great. I'll edit my post when I'm a bit further along so that it reflects my solution as well. Just got the first AT commands from my sony. Possibly related to me changing a privacy setting w.r.t. the Radio-control.
Again, thanks for the help!
PS-When you ever find out how to pass interfaces to a method of a different class via reflection then comment here as well as it makes the communication even easier via DataReader.